# Как в winServer 2008 настроить появление приветственного сообщения при подключении к домену?

Tags: windows-server-2008

Суть. Есть Windows Server 2008 с настроенным DNS и хостовые машины подключенные к этому домену. Нужно чтобы когда пользователь заходил с хостовой машины на домен выводилось приветственное сообщение. Что-то типа

```
"добро пожаловать на сервер %server_name%"
```

Блин, уже кажется всё, что можно перелопатил - так и не смог найти.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не уверен, что правильно понял вопрос, но если это так, то документ по ссылке будет полезен: [How to configure Windows Server 2003 to display a message when users log on](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310430).

Comment: спасибо за линк!